# How can I increment a number in a sub part of a string using sed command? and the input will be changed dynamically

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to increment sub part of string `version="01.00.00.041"` by 1 using `sed`.
For example: `version="01.00.00.041"` to `version="01.00.00.042"` and it should be dynamic not static. I mean, the version number will be changed everytime when I build, so it should be an input to the `sed` and last 1 digit should be incremented.

Edit: (collected from the comment)
I have tried like below:

```
sed -i "s/version.*/version=\"${print $ "."$ "."$ "."$ +1}}\">/g" descriptor.xml
```

Comment: What have you tried? This looks pretty simple. Here is an idea how to do it: Read the string using `read` shell builting with proper `IFS` to split it on full stop. Then increment the proper number with shell arithmetic expansion. Then print the number in proper format just by using `printf` shell builtin. And assign the output with proper format to another variable. `should be an input to the sed` - while this is possible in `sed`, it would take ca. 999 lines to do it in sed, it's completely impractical. `sed` is a simple regex replacement tool, it can't "increment" variable, use other tools

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I am new to linux and sed. This change is required in an xml file where the last digit needs to be updated based off of the previous version value exists in an xml file.  Please help me with an example or the sed command.  Thanks!

Comment: I have tried like below: sed -i "s/version.*/version=\"${print $  "."$  "."$  "."$ +1}}\">/g"  descriptor.xml

Comment: What is supposed to be the result when incrementing `01.00.00.999` ? Do you have to use just sed? Doing arithmetic with it is not entirely trivial.

Comment: only last digit needs to be incremented.  Once it reaches to "01.00.00.999", the next value will be bump up by us and which will be like "01.00.01.001".  So here only the concern to increment the last digit only using the sed and We really wont bother about the rest of the arthmetic logic. Hope I explained well.  Thank you!

Comment: This is a job for perl or awk, not sed.

Comment: @Ricky, Thank you for showing what you have tried, so kindly add them into your post too, as comments are not meant for adding codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP added an information so adding code as per information.

`awk -v version="version=\"01.00.00.42\"" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=".";s1="\""} match($0,version) && ++count==2{$NF+=1;$NF=$NF s1} 1'  Input_file`

---

Here is the working solution Added by OP:

```
grep version descriptor.xml | tail -n 1 | awk -F= '{print $2}' | awk -F\" '{print $2}' increatedNum=$(printf "%03d" expr $(echo $OldVersion | cut -d'.' -f4) + 1) NewVersion=echo $OldVersion | cut -d'.' -f1-3.$increatedNum sed -i "s/$OldVersion/$NewVersion/g" descriptor.xml
```

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=".";s1="\""} {$NF+=1;$NF=$NF s1} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
version="01.00.00.42"
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file itself use following then.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=".";s1="\""} {$NF+=1;$NF=$NF s1} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

---

---

OR as per @tshiono's comment you could try following too.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=".";s1="\""} {$NF+=1;$NF=sprintf("%03d%c", $NF, s1)} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: `$NF=sprintf("%03d%c", $NF, s1)` might be better if the OP wants it to be in three digits.

Comment: @tshiono, Sure, thank you sir, added your solution with your suggestion too cheers.

Comment: @Ricky, Sure, could you please check my EDIT solution and let me know then?

Comment: @Ricky,I have put `version=\"01.00.00.42\"` value to be checked in code, so if your actual value is NOT that one then you may need to put actual value in my code, kindly confirm if your actual value is different than `version=\"01.00.00.42\"` one?

Comment: @Ricky, oh ok, I have created a variable named `-v version="version=\"01.00.00.42\""` in code now, mention your variable here or pass it to here(in case it is a shell variable) then try and lemme know then?

Comment: @Ricky, could you please do let me know if this worked for you?

Comment: Solution below solved my problem:  OldVersion=`grep version descriptor.xml | tail -n 1 | awk -F= '{print $2}' | awk -F\" '{print $2}'`
increatedNum=$(printf "%03d" `expr $(echo $OldVersion | cut -d'.' -f4) + 1`)
NewVersion=`echo $OldVersion | cut -d'.' -f1-3`.$increatedNum
sed -i "s/$OldVersion/$NewVersion/g" descriptor.xml

Answer (score 2):

With perl:

```
$ echo 'version="01.00.00.041"' | perl -pe 's/(\d+)(?=")/sprintf("%0*d", length($1), $1+1)/e'
version="01.00.00.042"
```

Increments the last set of digits before a quote, with 0 padding based on the length of the field instead of a hardcoded number.